# Samba shared printer prints garbage

Tags: 14.04, windows-7, printing, samba

I have a printer connected to my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop which I share with other computers in my network using Samba. This setup works correctly with Ubuntu machines as well as Windows 8 machines. However I have a windows 7 laptop which detects the printer on the network and configures it but when I print something it prints out a bunch of text Similar to

```
@PJL COMMENT USERNAME="xyz"
@PJL COMMENT DOCNAME="Test Page"
@PJL SET COPIES=1
@PJL SET COLORMODE=MONO
.......
```

It prints the similar thing no matter what I print. Also I had installed Fedora 23 some time ago on the machine and setup the printer with it and in that setup the windows 7 machine could print without problems. However Fedora comes with it's own set of problems and going back to it isn't an option.

The printer is Samsung ML 2161. I have the drivers for it installed on the Windows machine and it obviously work on Ubuntu.

Any pointers as to what is wrong here?

Comment: This sounds like a Windows issue, not Ubuntu.  If it works on other machines (Windows and Ubuntu) then the issue is with your laptop.  I'd post this Q on SuperUser.

Comment: I thought that too till I setup Fedora 23 and it worked on that. At this point, either the samba config in ubuntu is the cause or maybe the samba version is (since Fedora 23 ships with version 4.3 while trusty ships with 4.1).

Comment: Could be the version.  Have you tried updating Sabma?

Comment: I tried looking around for a samba ppa but couldn't find one for trusty. If you know of one please do let me know. I don't want to build from source because I'm not really in the mood to maintain a service I build from source to be honest.

Comment: See my answer for some help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may need a newer version of Samba.

Ubuntu 14.04's default PPAs include Samba4.1.  Here's my server's feedback on `sudo apt-get install samba`:

```
user@host:~$ sudo apt-get install samba
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  attr libhdb9-heimdal libkdc2-heimdal python-dnspython samba-dsdb-modules
  samba-vfs-modules tdb-tools
Suggested packages:
  ldb-tools smbldap-tools winbind
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  attr libhdb9-heimdal libkdc2-heimdal python-dnspython samba
  samba-dsdb-modules samba-vfs-modules tdb-tools
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,515 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Selecting previously unselected package libhdb9-heimdal:amd64.
(Reading database ... 105333 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libhdb9-heimdal_1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libhdb9-heimdal:amd64 (1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1) ...
and blahblahblah
user@host:~$
```

So it appears that samba4.1's PPA comes with Ubuntu 14.04.

Here's the Samba 4.3 PPA: https://launchpad.net/~exekias/+archive/ubuntu/samba43.

Install the PPA, then you should be able to get Samba 4.3.

Try purging your current samba install and reinstalling.

Comment: Could you verify that the version of samba that you have is greater than 4.1.6.  Could you share the output of "apt-cache show samba | grep Version"

Comment: My bad, it is 4.1.6.

Comment: But here's the PPA for Samba 4.3: https://launchpad.net/~exekias/+archive/ubuntu/samba43